# Conditionally set the mouse cursor on a CMFCMenuButon control

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, cmfcmenubutton

I have a standard `CMFCMenuButton` control on my dialog:

```
CONTROL         "Congregation Link",IDC_MFCMENUBUTTON_CONGREGATION_LINK,
                "MfcMenuButton",WS_TABSTOP,257,60,159,14
```

This is the menu:

```
IDR_MENU_HYPERLINK_POPUP MENU
BEGIN
    POPUP "__HYPERLINK__"
    BEGIN
        MENUITEM "Add Hyperlink",               ID_ADD_HYPERLINK
        MENUITEM "Edit Hyperlink",              ID_EDIT_HYPERLINK
        MENUITEM "Remove Hyperlink",            ID_REMOVE_HYPERLINK
    END
END
```

I use standard approach to initialize the control:

```
void CCongregationDlg::InitCongregationLinkMenuButton()
{
    m_menuCongregationLink.LoadMenu(IDR_MENU_HYPERLINK_POPUP);
    m_menuBtnCongregationLink.m_hMenu = m_menuCongregationLink.GetSubMenu(0)->GetSafeHmenu();
    m_menuBtnCongregationLink.m_nFlatStyle = CMFCButton::BUTTONSTYLE_SEMIFLAT;

    // Resize (if required)
    CRect rctButton;
    m_menuBtnCongregationLink.GetWindowRect(&rctButton);
    const auto nOrigWidth = rctButton.Width(); // Store the original width
    const auto sizNewButton = m_menuBtnCongregationLink.SizeToContent(true); // This resizes the control!!!
    if (sizNewButton.cx > nOrigWidth) // Compare to the original width rather than the new one
    {
        m_menuBtnCongregationLink.SizeToContent();
    }
    else // Restore original width 
    {
        m_menuBtnCongregationLink.SetWindowPos(nullptr, -1, -1,
            nOrigWidth, sizNewButton.cy, SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_NOACTIVATE | SWP_NOZORDER);
    }
}
```

[image]

I would like to mimic a hyperlink:

1. When the mouse is over the text it will show a hand cursor.
2. When the mouse is over the drop-down arrow to display the menu it turns into a normal cursor.

Is this possible with the `CMFCMenuButton` control?

PS. Ideally it would show the link with an underline (much like the button hyperlink control)

Answer (score 1):

You have only to implement a WM_SETCURSOR handler. This should work for the button area.

Comment: Do I have to derive a new class to implement this handler?

Comment: You have to derive a new class from this button. Because you need to handle the message for the button. Standard subclassing will do the job too.

Answer (score 1):

I was looking up the documentation for [`CMFCMenuButton`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cmfcmenubutton-class?view=msvc-170) and I realised that it is derived from [`CMFCButton`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cmfcbutton-class?view=msvc-170).

And, that class have this method: [`CMFCButton::SetMouseCursorHand`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cmfcbutton-class?view=msvc-170#setmousecursorhand). To quote the documentation:

> Use this method to associate the cursor image of a hand with the button. The cursor is loaded from the application resources.

So I updated my `InitCongregationLinkMenuButton` method to include:

```
m_menuBtnCongregationLink.SetMouseCursorHand();
```

And it works:

[image]

I now have the hand cursor without the need to derive a new class. But it stays as a hand cursor even when the mouse is over the drop-arrow.